# Более короткая запись `case when ... end` для подсчёта числа строк (после группировки) удовлетворяющих условию

Tags: sql

У меня есть таблица у которой есть два столбца, `a` и `b`. Я хочу сгруппировать по столбцу `a` и для каждой группы посчитать число строк для которых `b` равно 7.

У меня получилось сделать это так:

```
select a, sum(case when b=7 then 1 else 0 end)
from table
group by a
```

Мне очень не нравится этот `case when ... end`. **Как можно записать его покороче?**

---

Пробовал писать `sum(b=7)` и даже `sum(convert(int, b=7))`, но получаю ошибку

> Incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: По стандартам SQL больше ни как, если бы у вас был конкретно MySQL то ваш b=7 бы сработал, так как там любой логический оператор возвращает 0 или 1 в виде числа. так же в некоторых СУБД есть свои функции для укороченной записи (или укороченное приведение типа boolean к числу). Но все это сильно зависит от конкретной СУБД, универсальных способов кроме case не существует

Comment: А что до самого case, то `else 0` можно убрать, правда в результате если нет b=7 будет NULL, вместо 0

Comment: понятно, спасибо, хотя обидно конечно

Comment: Кстати, а где вы convert откопали, он то совершенно не стандартен, его почти ни в одной СУБД нет. Я бы понял еще, если бы вы тип с помощью cast приводили, он хотя бы в половине распространенных БД есть (и в стандартах описан)

Comment: Вам нужно не только это сделать для группы, так? Иначе решается добавлением WHERE.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov `where` уберет те значения `a`, где нет `b=7` а так будет полный набор

Comment: @AlexanderZonov да, спасибо, в этом запросе `where` кажется бы подошёл, но в моём исходном запросе у меня два раза этот `sum(case when ... end)`, там с `where` не получится вроде

Comment: @Mike [первый результат](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24151332) по [запросу `sql bool to int`](https://www.google.ru/search?q=sql+bool+to+int)

Comment: Понятно. Ну convert как раз только в ms sql и есть :) И кстати, зачем вы стараетесь использовать универсальные средства ? Если нужно делать сложные запросы, оптимально для своей БД, то лучше по полной программе использовать все ее возможности. А если все таки нужна переносимость, то придется писать громоздко и возможно сильно терять в скорости работы.

Comment: @user268670, по идее, покороче не нужно записывать, а нужно так, чтобы использовались индексы. Попробовал на MySQL сейчас ваш запрос с explain и двумя sum/case, все нормально, если поле `a` индекс. Все хорошо с вашим запросом, скорее всего.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov тут точно не MySQL. А в каждой БД свои особенности оптимизации. Кстати, даже "_нужно так, чтобы использовались индексы_" не верно, бывает очень много ситуаций когда индексы не помогают, а замедляют запрос. И даже конкретно в этой ситуации. тут выбирается вся таблица, если колонка b лежит в данных, а индекс по "a", то лазание в данные по индексу зачастую гораздо медленнее чем full scan и sort. просто по тому, что головкам диска приходится носится из одной области диска в другую

Comment: @Mike, а в данном конкретном случае поможет ли index(a, b)?

Comment: я бы для читаемости написал так: `select a, count(case when b=7 then b else NULL end) from tab group by a;` - тогда сразу понятно что мы считаем, а не суммируем...

Comment: @MaxU тогда else точно не нужен. NULL он там по умолчанию

Comment: @Mike, [да, действительно](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1c699/6/0) - спасибо.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Да, (a,b) будет идеальным для данного запроса, практически при любых данных. Остается понять как часто выполняется этот запрос и как часто такой индекс сможет использоваться в других запросах в системе (а то вдруг раз в год такой запрос нужен, и других нет, держать индекс слишком дорого :) )

Comment: В Access есть iif и в какой-то редакции он перешел в MS SQL

Answer (score 3):

Вот немного более короткая и более понятная версия:

```
select a, count(case when b=7 then b end) as cnt from tab group by a;
```

`COUNT()` не учитывает `NULL` значения, а `CASE WHEN condition THEN ... END` возвращает `NULL` если `condition` не выполняется

PS спасибо [@Mike за подсказку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763251/%d0%91%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-case-when-end-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%87%d1%91%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d0%b8?noredirect=1#comment1185095_763251)

[SQL Fiddle Test ...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1c699/6/0)

Answer (score 2):

Стандартное решение без case:

```
select a, count(*)-count(nullif(b,7)) from tab group by a
```

Answer (score 2):

Если вы используете MS Access или MS SQL 2012+ , то там появилась альтернатива в виде [`iif`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql). Работает так же как и `CASE WHEN`, но короче.